# How to encode special characters in a launch file <param> element

Tags: ros, rospy, parameter, rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the following example, I would like to have the value of the parameter "myString" to contain only two ASCII characters: CarriageReturn and LineFeed. How do I specify them in the definition of a parameter in a launch file?

I've searched for the definition for all of the "special characters" but have not yet found the right combination of search terms.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12006/how-to-encode-special-characters-in-a-launch-file-%3Cparam%3E-element/) by [billmania](https://answers.ros.org/users/1420/billmania/) on ROS Answers with karma: 266 on 2011-11-21

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) on 2011-11-22**:
BTW, what is your actual use case here? I mean, \r\n is not your typical parameter, so I was wondering if there is another way to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Usually, you would encode CR and LF as the XML entities &#13; and &#10; respectively. However, roslaunch trims whitespace (including CR/LF) from the beginning and the end of a parameter string value (which is unfortunate and possibly a bug), and seems to apply the XML end-of-line handling (convert CR+LF and CR to LF) even to these encoded entities (which would be a bug in the XML parser).

---

Originally posted by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) with karma: 1951 on 2011-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0